# image to array / array to image, very strange display behaviour

Tags: c#, arrays, output, imaging

I am creating a custom `Byte[]` array from an `image`, Then i turn back that array into an Image and display it into a `PictureBox`.

```
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(fileimg));
byte[] arr = ImgToArr(img);
```

this works perfectly:

```
pictureBox1.Image = LineArr2Img(ImgToArr(img), cols, rows);  //return the correct image
```

Whereas this doesn't output the same image at all, its wrong:

```
pictureBox2.Image = LineArr2Img(arr, cols, rows);  //return an image that doesn't look quite img at all
```

Any idea Why??

Here are the functions used:

```
private Bitmap LineArr2Img(byte[] lineArr, int xx, int yy)   //ARRAY BACK TO IMAGE
        {
            var img = new Bitmap(xx, yy, xx,PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed,Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(lineArr, 0));
            return img;
        }


private unsafe byte[] ImgToArr(Bitmap img) //IMAGE TO ARRAY
        {
            var srcH = img.Height;
            var srcW = img.Width;
            var pxForm = img.PixelFormat;
            var pxFormSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(pxForm); 
            var imgArr = new byte[(srcH*srcW)];
            BitmapData srcData = img.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, srcW, srcH), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, pxForm);

                try
                {
                    byte* srcPointer = (byte*)srcData.Scan0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < srcH; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < srcW; j++)
                        {
                            imgArr[(j + (i * srcW))] = srcPointer[0];
                            srcPointer+=4;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception X) {
                    Console.WriteLine(X.ToString());
                }

            img.UnlockBits(srcData);
            return (byte[])imgArr;
        }
```

Comment: That's weird. It should work the same. Interesting!

Comment: i even did a For() to check both of all values, and they are 100% the same... very strange.

Comment: _var img = new Bitmap(xx, yy, xx,..._ this assumes the stride == width. Is it?? (Read: what is the width of the image?) Also: with 32bppARGB format instead of the 8ppIndexed, does it work? Finally: what is the __original__ format?

Comment: well with the 32bppARGB it is returning something interesting yes, but this is x-cloned because the array only contains 1byte per pixel.

Comment: I dont understand. i tested all PixelFormats, by curiosity. when i returned to `Format8bppIndexed` it is now working oO what the*???

Comment: _the array only contains 1byte per pixel_ What is the stride, what the width???

Comment: Well img is a RGBA image. I create the signle dimension array with using only R channel because RGB are all the same. (black and white picture). So the Stride is equal to Width. and images aren't much big around 400 width only max

Comment: Um, I don't think so.  The line I mean is this: _var img = new Bitmap(xx, yy, xx,PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed_ and that is not ARGB and stride is only== width if width & 4 == 0; See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _The stride is the width of a single row of pixels (a scan line), rounded up to a four-byte boundary. If the stride is positive, the bitmap is top-down. If the stride is negative, the bitmap is bottom-up._